# When is the Weyl tensor applied on null vectors a null vector?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

Let $C^{\rho}_{~\alpha \beta \gamma}$ be the Weyl tensor of a spacetime $(M,g)$, that is a solution to Einstein's equation. Let $X^\alpha, Y^\alpha, Z^\alpha$ be null vector fields, i.e. $X_\alpha X^\alpha = Y_\alpha Y^\alpha = Z_\alpha Z^\alpha = 0$.

Are there conditions on $(M,g)$ s.th.

\begin{equation}
k^\rho := C^\rho_{~\alpha \beta \gamma} X^\alpha Y^\beta Z^\gamma
\end{equation}

is a null vector field, i.e. $k^\rho k_\rho = 0$? Does this maybe hold for vacuum solutions of Einstein's equations?

Comment: are X,Y,Z arbitrary null vectors?

Comment: Yes. But partial results (with e.g. further restrictions on X, Y, Z) are also highly appreciated!